# Google OR Tools, "returned a result with an exception set" Error on my server

Tags: exception, routes, digital-ocean, or-tools

I am using ORTools for path optimization. When I try my code in localhost it returns the expected result. However, when I try it on my DigitalOcean App it gives an error message:" returned a result with an exception set". Can anyone help me to find a solution ?

Here is the TraceBack code from Postman if it is useful:

**The above exception ('numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer) was the direct cause of the following exception:**

Local vars
/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ortools/constraint_solver/pywrapcp.py, line 5730, in GetArcCostForVehicle

```
    return _pywrapcp.RoutingModel_CostVar(self)
def GetArcCostForVehicle(self, from_index: "int64_t", to_index: "int64_t", vehicle: "int64_t") -> "int64_t":
    r"""
    Returns the cost of the transit arc between two nodes for a given vehicle.
    Input are variable indices of node. This returns 0 if vehicle < 0.
    """
    return _pywrapcp.RoutingModel_GetArcCostForVehicle(self, from_index, to_index, vehicle) …
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check that all your transit callbacks are returning an **int** type.

In your code you must have registered a transit callback:

```py
# Create and register a transit callback.
def distance_callback(from_index, to_index):
    """Returns the distance between the two nodes."""
    # Convert from routing variable Index to distance matrix NodeIndex.
    from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
    to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
    return data['distance_matrix'][from_node][to_node]

transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(distance_callback)
```

then you have passed this `transit_callback_index` to setup the arc cost evaluator function.

```
# Define cost of each arc.
routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)
```

The point is, the function `distance_callback()` will be call internally by the C++ library (python is just a wrapper on top of the C++ library). The C++ expect a C++ `int64_t` returned by the `distance_callback()` wrapper function (i.e. the python-C++ bridge need an `int` from the python method to be able to convert it to a C++ `int64_t`).

If your method return a `numpy.float64` (e.g. because you r distance matrix data are an numpy array full of floating point values) then everything blow up thus the error message...

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean by that. I have already checked that I give int parameters to GetArcCostForVehicle() method if it is what you saying. I still couldn't find a solution :(

Comment: Also how can it be possible that it runs normally on my local server but gives error in digital ocean cloud server. Also, It doesn't give error at every try, sometimes it works sometimes don't at there.

Comment: What do you mean by transit callback ?

Comment: I would say different version of the python runtime so one produce undefined behaviour while the other detect the bad convertion and throw an error ?
note: native package are loaded (dlopen...) in the python runtime and will use the python symbols already loaded by the runtime.